# Outline only the outside of mesh (depending on camera angle)

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

How can I create an outline, using solidfy, only on the outside of the mesh (no the inside) even depending on the camera view.

for example, with the model below, the inside of the object still has outlines, only the outside should. And this should be no matter the position the camera is view the object.

[image]

Comment: I think what you're looking for a *Freestyle*, which allows you to draw outlines. Solidify doesn't seem like the right tool for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I tried that, but I kept getting gaps, and it still outlines the inside contents. What settings should I use?

Comment: There is no direct built-in feature that does this. 
You could try to tweak the settings of the freestyle, e.g. try going by material border.
You could also try to use the double edge mask, or the dilate/erode in the compositor. If your object is not on a transparent BG you can use object/material Masks.

Comment: Are you using [this technique](http://blendernpr.org/solidify-modifier-contouroutline/), and having problems with it?

Comment: Yes, I am using that technique.